# Java - class expected error

Tags: string

I have the following code:

```
import javax.sqing.JOptionPane;
public class DebugTwo4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         string costString;
         double cost;
         final double TAX = 0.06;
         costString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter price of item you are buying", "Purchases", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         cost = double.parsecost (coststring);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"With " + TAX * 100 + "% tax, purchase is $" + (cost - cost * TAX));
    }
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
DebugTwo4.java:11: error: class expected
    cost = double.parsecost (coststring);

DebugTwo4.java:11: error: ';' expected
    cost = double.parsecost (coststring);
```

Please help!

Comment: In the future, type out your code within your answer. It will make answering a whole lot easier than trying to read/re-type what you have in the screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your code *in* the question itself. Also be sure to clearly explain the error you're getting, what you've tried to do to fix it, and what specifically you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `parsecost` is supposed to do since I don't see a definition for it anywhere, but from what I understand could you not change this line:

```
cost = double.parsecost (coststring);
```

To something like this:

```
cost = Double.parseDouble(coststring);
```